# ASP.NET MVC ActionFilter parameter binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, action-filter

If you have a model-bound parameter in an action method, how can you get to that parameter in an action filter?

```
[MyActionFilter]
public ActionResult Edit(Car myCar)
{
    ...
}

public class MyActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        //I want to access myCar here
    }

}
```

Is there anyway to get myCar without going through the Form variables?

Comment: Here is a great article explaining how to access ActionParameters for authorization purposes: http://www.joe-stevens.com/2010/08/19/asp-net-mvc-authorize-attribute-using-action-parameters-with-the-actionfilterattribute/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not sure about OnActionExecuted but you can do it in OnActionExecuting:

```
public class MyActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // I want to access myCar here

        if(filterContext.ActionParameters.ContainsKey("myCar"))
        {
            var myCar = filterContext.ActionParameters["myCar"] as Car;

            if(myCar != null)
            {
                // You can access myCar here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can use ActionFilter there, it is ActionFilterAttribute. Also where did you get the ActionParameters property on the ActionExecutedContext?

Comment: Thanks, it is ActionFilterAttribute - you are right. I have not noticed that the question is about OnActionExecuted.

Comment: Thanks guys. Edited my original question to state ActionFilterAttribute.

Comment: Great answer however "if(filterContext.ActionParameters["myCar"] is Car) filterContext.ActionParameters["myCar"] as Car" is a little better.